# UFS filesystem creation date

Tags: solaris

How can I find out when a UFS filesystem was created on a Solaris 8 machine?

Answer (score 1):

You can't tell the date of a filesystem, but you can try to search for the oldest files on it... typically /lost+found

ls -lat /lost+found

Comment: Not a bad idea for a "not later than" bound on creation date, but it's **guaranteed** to be wrong in terms of actual creation date.  No file system is created with files in `/lost+found`, as that would partially defeat the purpose of the directory.  If there are any files in it, they'll date no earlier than the first time the file systems was made dirty, fscked, and detached inodes were found.

Comment: I was not refering to files in lost+found but the lost+found folder itself, as it's a file it has a date.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps look at when the block devices were created by running "`ls -lrt /dev/dsk`". 
You can also check the parameters used to create a ufs file system by running mkfs -m against the raw device, for example "`mkfs -m /dev/rdsk/c0t0d0s4`"

hth.